# Запустить скрипт python без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, веб-программирование, cgi

Добрый вечер. Создаю одностраничный сайт, с помощью python. Суть - нужно отправить данные из textarea на сторону сервера, на сервере с помощью python провести манипуляции(закодировать шифром Цезаря), и вернуть текст обратно в textbox. Передача данных должна осуществляться через json. Не выходит реализовать отправку данных и их возврат без перезагрузки. Прошу помощи.

```html
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Caesar cipher</title>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.btn').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('cgi-bin/script.py', function(data) {
          $('#output-box').val(data);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <legend>Caesar cipher</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <form name="ciepher">
        <div class="span5">
          <textarea id="input-box" name="text" class="span5" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="span2" id="controls">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">ROT</span>
            <input class="input-mini" name="rotate" type="number" size="3">
          </div>
          <div id="buttons">
            <button class="btn" name="decrypt" value="decrypt" id="decrypt"><span class="icon-arrow-left"></button>
      <button class="btn" name="encrypt" value="encrypt" id="encrypt"><span class="icon-arrow-right"></button>
     </div>
      </div>
    <div class="span5">
     <textarea id="output-box" class="span5" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
      </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>`
```

**Код Python:**

```
import cgi
import html
import json

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text = html.escape(form.getvalue("text", ""))
rotate = int(html.escape(form.getvalue("rotate", "")))
alpha_upper = [chr(x) for x in range(ord("A"), ord("Z")+1)]
alpha_lower = [chr(x) for x in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1)]
ALPHA_LENGTH = 26 # 26 - количество английских букв

def encode_formula(alphabet):
        code = (alphabet.index(char) + rotate) % ALPHA_LENGTH  
        return alphabet[code]
def decode_formula(alphabet):
        code = (alphabet.index(char) - rotate + ALPHA_LENGTH) % ALPHA_LENGTH  
        return alphabet[code]

def encode():
    result = ""
    for char in text:
        if char in alpha_upper:
            result += encode_formula(alpha_upper)
        elif char in alpha_lower:
            result += encode_formula(alpha_lower)
        else:
            result += char
    with open("text.json","w") as file:
        json.dump(result, file)
    return result
def decode():
    result = ""
    for char in text:
        if char in alpha_upper:
            result += decode_formula(alpha_upper, char, rot)
        elif char in alpha_lower:
            result += decode_formula(alpha_lower, char, rot)
        else:
            result += char
    with open("text.json","w") as file:
        json.dump(result, file)
    return result

if form.getvalue("encrypt"):  # Если нажата кнопка encrpyt 
    print(json.dump(encode()))
if form.getvalue("decrypt"):  # Если нажата кнопка decrpyt 
    print(json.dump(decode()))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: *«Не выходит реализовать отправку данных и их возврат без перезагрузки. Прошу помощи.»* — не информативно. При возникновении ошибок, опишите словами что вы ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит (по шагам). Уберите всё не нужное: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

добавьте "return false" в ваш js код;

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('script.html', function(data) {
      $('#output-box').val(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

AJAX запрос—это правильный подход, чтобы получить данные без перезагрузки страницы.

Чтобы найти ошибку, тестируйте клиент и сервер отдельно. Например, замените Питон-скрипт на сервере на статичный json файл—`response.json`:

```
{"data": "some data"}
```

А затем запросите этот файл на клиенте—`index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Пример как получить JSON данные по нажатию на кнопку, не перегружая страницу</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Не меняется. Остаётся на месте</p>
<a href="#" id=get-data>Нажми, чтобы получить JSON данные</a>
<div id=show-data>Здесь результат показывается</div>
<script>
    $('#get-data').click(function () { // отправляем запрос по нажатию на кнопку
      $.getJSON('response.json', function (json) {
        $('#show-data').text('Результат: ' + json.data); // показываем результат
      }).fail(function() {
        console.log("не удалось json получить");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Чтобы попробовать, достаточно запустить `python3 -mhttp.server` команду из директории, которая содержит `index.html` и `response.json`, и посетить `http://localhost:8000`.

Убедитесь что это у вас работает, а затем изменяйте `html`-код до желаемого состояния, на каждом шаге проверяя, что код всё ещё работает.

---

Чтобы протестировать сервер, делайте http-запросы напрямую:

```
$ http localhost:8000/response.json
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 22
Content-type: application/json
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 08:18:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 07:05:34 GMT
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.4.3+

{
    "data": "some data"
}
```

[`http` утилита отсюда](http://httpie.org).

Убедитесь, что ваш cgi питон-скрипт возвращает ожидаемые значения, при прямых запросах.